# How to get list of Mutual friends,Following and Followers

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I read many questions here about mutual friends and following and followers but i can't solved my problem, I have two tables like these.

- User_table ( UID, Name)
- Relation_table (RID, UID,UIDF)

for example in user_table have 4 users

```
UID | Name
------------------
1   |  Kim Tessman
2   |  Nella Ohler
3   |  Adria Larose
4   |  Huey Errico
```

And Relation_table have these data

```
RID | UID | UIDF
------------------
1   | 1   | 2
2   | 2   | 1
3   | 1   | 4
4   | 4   | 3
5   | 4   | 1
```

my questions are :

1. how to get list of Mutual friends ?
2. how to get list of Following ?
3. how to get list of Followers ?

please who can solve this problem thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the UID column in the Relation_Table is the user and that the UIDF is the person they are following. Here is the SQL query that finds who a person is following. The who is being followed is the same query, you just focus on the other name column or switch the column order around.

Here is a list of who follows who. It is also the list of who is being followed.

```
SELECT     FollowingUser.UID as FollowingUserID, FollowingUser.Name,  BeingFollowed.UID AS BeingFollowedID, BeingFollowed.Name AS BeingFollowedName
FROM         User_table AS FollowingUser INNER JOIN
                  Relation_Table AS r ON FollowingUser.UID = r.uid INNER JOIN
                  User_table AS BeingFollowed ON r.uidf = BeingFollowed.UID
```

And this query gives you the list of mutual friends - but it gives the inverse of the relationship. If this matters, add this to the end `where FollowingUser.UID > BeingFollowed.UID`

```
SELECT     FollowingUser.UID AS FollowingUserID, FollowingUser.Name, BeingFollowed.UID AS BeingFollowedID, BeingFollowed.Name AS BeingFollowedName
FROM         User_table AS FollowingUser INNER JOIN
                  Relation_Table AS r ON FollowingUser.UID = r.uid INNER JOIN
                  Relation_Table AS r1 ON r.uid = r1.uidf AND r.uidf = r1.uid INNER    JOIN
                  User_table AS BeingFollowed ON r1.uid = BeingFollowed.UID
```